# What is the way to get ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET for twitter to verify a user

Tags: android, oauth, twitter

I am a beginner in android.
I have registered an app to twitter and i got CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET. Now
i want to write a code so that it will retrive ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET and ACCESS_TOKEN to verify a user.( I have tried some code but those do not work. I think those are old )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php